# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'opencage-api-client'

Tags: reactjs, deployment

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'opencage-api-client' in '/var/www/html/Weather-AQI-App/src/component/location' getting this error in production build why

1. Check if the 'opencage-api-client' package is listed in your project's dependencies in the 'package.json' file. If it's not there, you need to install it by running the following command in your project's root directory.

2.If the package is already listed in your 'package.json' file, try deleting the 'node_modules' folder and reinstalling all dependencies. Run the following commands in your project's root directory:
$rm -rf node_modules
$npm install

The second option worked for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.